# How to return the generated function to the form of mathematical expression and perform derivation and other operations on it in python?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, derivative

After using curve_fitting from scipy,the scatter data is fitted by Gaussian approximation,the code is as follows:

```
x = np.linspace(1,len(y),len(y)) 
n = len(x)
mean = sum(x*y)/n
sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n)

def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))
popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,x,y,maxfev = 200000)
```

When I call it, the generated p1 is just an array corresponding to x：

`p1 = gaus(x,*popt)` 
,The returned array is：

```
[0.09933219 0.10139629 0.10350315 0.10565368 0.10784877 0.11008935
 0.11237635 0.11471073 0.11709347 0.11952557 0.12200806 0.12454196
 0.12712835 0.1297683  0.13246293 0.13521337 0.13802076 0.14088628
 0.14381113 0.14679655 0.14984377 0.15295407 0.15612876 0.15936917
 0.16267665 0.16605259 0.1694984  0.17301552 0.17660543 0.18026962
 0.18400963 0.18782703 0.19172341 0.19570039 0.19975966 0.20390289
 0.20813183 0.21244823 0.21685392 0.22135072 0.22594052 0.23062523
 0.23540682 0.24028728 0.24526864 0.250353   0.25554246 0.26083921
 0.26624545 0.27176344 0.27739549 0.28314393 0.28901118 0.29499968
 0.30111193 0.30735049 0.31371794 0.32021696 0.32685025 0.33362057
 0.34053076 0.34758369 0.3547823  0.36212959 0.36962863 0.37728255
 0.38509452 0.39306781 0.40120574 0.4095117  0.41798914 0.42664161
 0.4354727  0.4444861  0.45368554 0.46307487 0.472658   0.4824389
 0.49242166 0.50261042 0.51300944 0.52362302 0.53445559 0.54551166
 0.55679582]
```

In this case, how can I find it's first derivative expression, the second derivative and so on for the generated function?

Comment: You could try https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html, but I suggest either differentiating yourself, or use https://www.sympy.org (Python symbolic math package).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`.

First, you need to create a spline of your data as:

```python
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

spl = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, p1)
```

Afterward, you can use the `spl` object to pass `x` and `n` (the number of derivative), to get a new spline as `np.ndarray` at `x` with its nth derivative as:

```python
der1 = spl(x, 1)
der2 = spl(x, 2)
```